# angular material calendar not showing properly

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, mat-form-field

this is the html code i wrote

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY – MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

styles.css

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
```

app.module.ts code
note : i didnt show all the imports i wrote

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker'
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input'
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field'
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    LogoutComponent,
    ActualteComponent,
    ForumComponent,
    AgendaComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatNativeDateModule
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfblG.png)

i used the code from the official angular material website and its like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY9Qb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I too had some issues when using the mat-date picker component from angular here's what i did

- I used the same html code you posted
- Added Angular material using ng add @angular/material
- I had to import some more modules other than the date picker module as i encountered some errors. Here's my app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {MatNativeDateModule} from '@angular/material/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I restarted the app and ran it and it worked fine for me.

I didn't have to do the import for the deep purple theme as it showed the option to select one when adding the angular material.

My Angular version is **Angular: 15.1.5** and the material version is  **"@angular/material": "^15.1.5"**,